# grid view image display error in Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio

Code for picking an image from gallery

```
    private void pickImageFromGallery() {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_CODE:{
                if(grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0]== PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    pickImageFromGallery();

                }else {

                    Toast.makeText(this,"access denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To handle the picked image, i inflated the `layout_ticket` which contains image view.
Assigned the image to it which i picked.

```
// handle the picked image
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK && requestCode==IMAGE_PICK_CODE){
            LayoutInflater mInflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View myView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ticket, null);
            ImageView imageview = (ImageView) myView.findViewById(R.id.imageview);

            imageview.setImageURI(data.getData());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please attach your error

Comment: no error, its just unable to display my imported image from gallery